# select where id not in (another table with where condition (data that fetch from two date interval))

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I want to know the where not in and between date intervals works separately. But it doesn't work in one query.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('admission');
$this->db->where("'ad_no' not in (SELECT 'ad_no' FROM 'payment' WHERE( 
'date' BETWEEN DATE_SUB(date(), INTERVAL $acc DAY) AND date()') )");
$query=$this->db->get()->result_array();
return $query;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems you are not usiing the proper column name for date 
Furthermore You have wrong single quote and should avoid unuseful ()

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('admission');
  $this->db->where("'ad_no' not in (SELECT 'ad_no' FROM 'payment' WHERE  
  'date' BETWEEN DATE_SUB('date', INTERVAL $acc DAY) AND 'date' ) ");
  $query=$this->db->get()->result_array();
  return $query;
```